# Displaying a small float shows up as 5.424E-5 in PHP

Tags: php

How do I display a small float value like the following in PHP?

```
0.0048 * 1130000 = 5424

5424 / 100000000 = 5.424E-5
```

This should be **0.00005424**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo echo number_format(5424 / 100000000,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

number_format - doest the trick

```
$FeeInBTC = number_format( (DB_GetFee() * $fOrderQty)/100000000,9,'.','');
```

result:
**0.000054240**

Answer (score 0):

If by display you mean convert to string in the format `0.00005424`, you can use `sprintf()` like so:

```
$string = sprintf("%f", 5424 / 100000000)
```